# Check if a relation is loaded in Yii

Tags: php, yii

I'm trying to do something complex with a relation and avoid double loading:

- I have an `object` active record and each has a relation to some `subject`s through an `objectSubject` relation.
- The type of the `subject` (in relation to the `object`) is defined in the `objectSubject` with another relation.
- Each `object` has zero or one `subject` relation of each type

I have the relations set up in the `Object` model as:

```
'objectSubjects'=>array(self::HAS_MANY, 'ObjectSubject', 'object_id'),
```

And the `ObjectSubject` model as:

```
'type'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Type', 'type_id'),
'subject'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Subject', 'subject_id'),
```

I would like to add a function to `Object` get the `subject` of an `object` by it's `type`..

I can do:

```
public function fetchSubject($key_string){
  $object_subject=$this->objectSubjects(array(
       'with'=>'subject'
       'scopes'=>array('typed'=>$key_string) /* Inner Join to type */
  ));
  return $object_subjects?$object_subjects[0]->subject:null;
}
```

But this will result in a DB query, even if the `object_subject`s with their `type`s and `subject`s are eagerly loaded into the `object`.

I would like to substitute the logic in the case that they are, and only query the one `subject` row if they are not.. is there any way to check if a relation has been loaded?

Something like `$this->isLoaded('objectSubjects')`?

Answer (score 4):

Well what do you know? There is a function

```
hasRelated(string $name)
```

that I totally missed in the [AR docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#hasRelated-detail).